# How to build a Recommendation System using Implicit dataset with strong timeliness?

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I have a dataset that has, **users**, **items** and **views**,which is the interaction between user and item.

The only difference in this dataset from the other recommendation datasets is that, the items have strong timeliness i.e. the items expires after a certain time period and won't be considered anymore.(Items life span can range from 1 week - 4 months)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Bayesian Personalized Ranking for implicit feedback](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.2618). I wrote about my experience of building such [recommendation systems using Tensorflow](https://medium.com/heyjobs-tech/building-recommendation-system-based-bayesian-personalized-ranking-using-tensorflow-2-1-b814d2704130).

Regarding timeliness, you should use only active items to find recommendations.

For an example of the workflow can look like:

- you need to recommend 5 items;
- you ask the system to give you 30 recommendations using only active items;
- then exclude items that will expire in the next 2 days;
- then randomly select 5 from those who stayed;

Comment: Thank you @Danylo for your answer. I am using only the active items for my recommendation and actually used the Implicit library. The main issue I have noticed with data with strong timeliness is that they cannot generate views in a short period of time, and that affects my recommendation.